# What is the font name for Source Sans Pro

Tags: fonts

When using multiple sans-serif fonts in one document, it is necessary to know the internal name of a font to use it, as described here: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/25251#25251)

Unfortunately, I was not able to determine the internal name for the Source Sans Pro font (package: sourcesanspro). So my question is: what is the internal name for this font?

---

To be more precise:

1. I use pdflatex.
2. I would like to do something like:

   ```
   \fontfamily{xyz}\selectfont
   ```

   where I need to know, what "xyz" would be.

Comment: do you mean the latex family name (for pdftex) or the actual internal font name of the font for use with fontspec? (the latex family names like phv for helvetica are not a property of the font just of the tex macros)

Comment: Are you using xeLaTeX and fontspec? The name of the font family is `Source Sans Pro`, the  name of the font files are `SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf`,  `SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf`, &c.

Comment: Thanks for the first comments! I edited my original question to be more precise.

Answer (score 7):

The font family can be derived without analyzing the source code. LaTeX stores the current family name in macro `\f@family`. Thus, generate a short test document that uses the font as you need it. Check the package options of `sourcesanspro`. Then the value of `\f@family` is output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lining]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\textsf{Family of Source Sans Pro: \textcolor{red}{\f@family}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

you need the family name, looking at

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sourcesanspro/tex

you will see the names are all of the form

```
SourceSansPro-TLF
```

where the part after the `-` depends on the options you specified for the styles of numbers to use, etc.

A line like

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{SourceSansPro-TLF}{b}{it}{
```

in one of those files is declaring T1 encoded font in family SourceSansPro-TLF bold italic variant.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the .fd files, you have `4` font families:

- `SourceSansPro-LF`: with proportional lining figures,
- `SourceSansPro-OsF`: with proportional old-style figures,
- `SourceSansPro-TLF`: with tabular lining figures,
- `SourceSansPro-OsF`: with tabular old-style figures,

and two smaller font families:

- `SourceSansPro-Numr`: with numerator figures,
- `SourceSansPro-Sup`: with superior figures (for exponents; recommended for footnote numbers, for instance).

All thses families are much simpler to use with `fontspec`, since you only have one Open Type family, and you call for a specific `\fontfeature`.